# Windows file sharing for only 1 NIC

Tags: windows, security, file-sharing

Our Windows 2008 servers are at a Data Center. Both have 2 network cards. One card is connected to the switch that connects to the Internet the other is connected to a switch that serves only our servers. We would like to enable file sharing so that our servers can share files, but only through the local switch/network card.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to disable any SMB access on that second NIC, it's pretty simple. When you go into the NICs properties, where you set the IP settings, remove the checkmarks next to the Windows services. This unbinds the service from the port, and prevents people from accessing it. For bonus points remove the 'Register this connection in DNS' checkbox in the DNS tab, that way you won't have the wrong IP in DNS to confuse clients.